# How do I use a function pointer in an objective c pod, in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

so maybe this is not exactly a function pointer, but its the closest analogy I can find since Im new to both Swift and Objective C

I have this Pod, which is in Objective C. It has a public interface defined as such:

```
@interface FLAnimatedImageView : UIImageView
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^animationCompletionBlock)();
```

The idea here is that the object of type FLAnimatedImageView can call a custom routine referenced by animationCompletionBlock which will run when an animation completes. Atleast this is what I understand from reading the code

So in the swift code that uses this pod, I have a object of type FLAnimatedImageView, called foo

how does foo delcare and invoke the animationCompletionBlock? Maybe this is a basic swift syntax type of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

Create a function like for example:

```
func do_this_when_animation_ends() -> Void {
              // stuff
    }
```

Now set

```
foo.animationCompletionBlock = do_this_when_animation_ends
```

Thats it!

Comment: Well done. Might have been useful to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_as_value